# Is this item unbalanced?

Tags: numenera

We are playing Numenera, and due to a series of previous diversions from our main quest, our group decided that we needed to make a bee-line straight for the main quest. Along the way, we decided to search for a faster means of travel.

The DM obliged, and presented us with an item called the "Pure Heart". I took it, and following general indications, held it to my chest. Basically it was a parasite, it burrowed into my chest, consumed my heart and ate it. I immediately took 20 flat damage, and immediately impaired and debilitated.

Fortunately I was able to recover the damage, but as per the GM's instruction I can't remove the impaired status until he sees fit.

I do get the bonus that I can interact with a "unicorn" creature, and I get a +1 to my Might edge. However the downside is that any time I roll a 1, the heart dies, and my character goes into cardiac arrest. Without a replacement, my character dies. I asked if I could spend an experience point to re roll it, and he said no, the heart would still fail regardless.

I'm feeling like this is a bit unbalanced. Is it?

Comment: Do you have an idea of how easy it is to get a replacement heart? If it's challenging, then giving a player a 5% chance to die no matter what they roll sounds exceptionally cruel unless the DM has something else in store for you.

Comment: @Dumpcats it depends on the situation. In a cave in the middle of nowhere (which is where we're currently headed): no chance. In town, I can purchase one from the body shop

Comment: The re roll can still happen, and I can change the success of the roll, however the intervention still stands. That's withon the rules of numenera

Comment: In numenera, if a player rolls a 1, the GM is allowed to 'intervene', or create an unfortunate situation that normally occurs when a 1 is rolled. The player can choose to re roll to succeed in the roll, and successfully hit, climb, dodge, whatever. However, the GM is still allowed to intervene, since the 1 was rolled, regardless of the re roll

Comment: @Ben I'd like to see the rule that says "the GM is still allowed to intervene, since the 1 was rolled, regardless of the re roll". A reroll is a reroll. The previous roll is no more. It has ceased to be. Bereft of life...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The item is not unbalanced. The problem is that neither yourself nor your GM understands intrusions. *Intrusions are not there to kill a character or for the GM to impose their will on the player.* This is a breach of the letter and spirit of the rules of Numenera and the Cypher system.

First, your GM should have offered an intrusion to have your heart replaced: you could have refused it with an XP or accepted it with its consequences (your heart is replaced), and XP for you, and one XP for whomever you chose to. You, as the player, might even have been told what would happen if you chose to accept the intrusion.

Second, if on 5% chance of a dice roll, your character dies and you create a new one. That is just arbitrary and an abuse of player agency. And this is definitely not what intrusions are about.

Finally, your GM might have a story reason for your death not to be the end. In that case, your GM just killed death… But that can work I guess. We do not have enough information. In any case, your GM should have checked that you were okay with a major shift of character otherwise it is violating player agency.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I don't think we can fairly judge whether an item your GM presented is unbalanced. Since your GM presented it, there are very likely factors which are unknown to you.

If I were to judge based only on the information presented, I'd say a 5% chance of dying every time you roll a 1 (presumably when you roll a 1 while using the extra edge?) is a little out of balance. If it's ANY 1, it's more than a little out of balance.

But again, I suspect there's more to it than you've been told so far.

Edit: After the question edit, I still don't think there is enough information to judge the question of balance. However, Sardathrion's answer does more to address the underlying issues of the concept.

Comment: Edited the question to add a bit more info - I asked if re rolling would change anything, and he said no